# the name does not exist in current context - but I've put my varaible in class

Tags: unity-game-engine

code:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Runner : MonoBehaviour {

    public static float distanceTraveled;
    private static int boosts;
    public float acceleration;
    public Vector3 boostVelocity, jumpVelocity;
    public float gameOverY;
    public float highScore = 0f;

    private bool touchingPlatform;
    private Vector3 startPosition;

    void Start () {
        GameEventManager.GameStart += GameStart;
        GameEventManager.GameOver += GameOver;
        startPosition = transform.localPosition;
        renderer.enabled = false;
        rigidbody.isKinematic = true;
        enabled = false;
    }

    void Update () {
        if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)){
            if(touchingPlatform){
                rigidbody.AddForce(jumpVelocity, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
                touchingPlatform = false;
            }
            else if(boosts > 0){
                rigidbody.AddForce(boostVelocity, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
                boosts -= 1;
                GUIManager.SetBoosts(boosts);
            }
        }
        distanceTraveled = transform.localPosition.x;
        GUIManager.SetDistance(distanceTraveled);

        if(transform.localPosition.y < gameOverY){
            GameEventManager.TriggerGameOver();
        }
        // the bit i car about                     <----------------------
        if(distanceTraveled > highScore) {
            highScore = distanceTraveled;
        }

    }

    void FixedUpdate () {
        if(touchingPlatform){
            rigidbody.AddForce(acceleration, 0f, 0f, ForceMode.Acceleration);
        }
    }

    void OnCollisionEnter () {
        touchingPlatform = true;
    }

    void OnCollisionExit () {
        touchingPlatform = false;
    }

    private void GameStart () {
        boosts = 0;
        GUIManager.SetBoosts(boosts);
        distanceTraveled = 0f;
        GUIManager.SetDistance(distanceTraveled);
        transform.localPosition = startPosition;
        renderer.enabled = true;
        rigidbody.isKinematic = false;
        enabled = true;
    }

    private void GameOver () {
        renderer.enabled = false;
        rigidbody.isKinematic = true;
        enabled = false;
    }

    public static void AddBoost(){
        boosts += 1;
        GUIManager.SetBoosts(boosts);
    }
}
```

i get a 'variable distance does not exist in the current context, but I defined the variable in the class, so its there. What happens to it?

Comment: Just to be clear, the line with the arrow is the line that the error points to, correct?

Comment: distanceTraveled is static, you have to access it as `Runner.distanceTraveled`

Comment: OK I've replaced both with Runner.distanceTravelled, the error still comes up (for the same lines). What gives?

Comment: You haven't initialized it. Try adding "= 0.0f" when you declare it to initialize it to zero. Also, and I'm just guessing, you probably don't want that to be a static variable.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried restarting Unity? Your code seems to work fine.

Comment: tried it, no luck :( what could it be? The error message is 'the name 'distance' does not exist in the current context'

Comment: distance? you don't have a variable distance.. is this the final version of your code?

Comment: i know right? This won't be near final, but I don't have anything called 'distance' and the error links to (44,46)

Comment: you say you have an error that a non-existent variable doesn't exist in you code... what you posted doesn't give a syntax error for me. I would suggest closing monodevelop / vs and re-importing and re-syncing the scripts.

Comment: to be clear, (44,46) after the cs name is the line numbers, right?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you haven't initialized it at start so maybe that's it.